# Wrong order of selectedItem while using onChange in a dropdown & using material-ui

Tags: reactjs

Well, I have a dropdown and I want to use the `onChange() selectedItem` to then call an API and render the output using map.
My code looks something like this:

**TaskSideBar.js**

```
const taskAPI = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/';

export default class TaskSideBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        pokeData: [],
        pokeIndex: null,
        isLoading: false,
        error: null,
        };
      this.handleDropdownChange = this.handleDropdownChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  }
handleDropdownChange(e) {
    this.setState({selectedValue: e.target.value})
      fetch(taskAPI + this.state.selectedValue )
         .then(response => {
           if (response.ok) {
             return response.json();
             } else {
               throw new Error('something is wrong');
             }
          })
         .then (data => this.setState({ pokeData: data.results, pokeIndex: 0, isLoading: false }))
         .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }

render () {
    const { pokeData, pokeIndex, isLoading, error, selectedValue, renderRow } = this.state;
    const classes = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <Tabs tabs={['Reports', 'Graphs', 'Sheets']} className={classes.sidebarTabs}>
          <>
            <h3>Reports</h3>
            <List source={reportItems} />
          </>
          <>
            <h3>Graphs</h3>
            <Dropdown source={graphItems}  />
          </>
          <>
            <h3>Sheets</h3>
            <select id="dropdown" onChange={this.handleDropdownChange} className={classes.taskList}>
              <option value="">select </option>
              <option value="berry">Pokemon Berry</option>
              <option value="ability">Pokemon Abilities</option>
              <option value="version">Version Info</option>
            </select>
          </>
        </Tabs>
        <div>
          selected sheet is: {this.state.selectedValue}
          {
            pokeData.map(hit =>
                <div key={hit.name}>
                  <p> {hit.name} {hit.url} </p>
                </div>
            )
          }
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

What is actually happening is, once the page renders and I select 'berry', I get an error: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/undefined': 404. So that means for some reason, the `selectedValue` was not set to 'berry'. However, if I then go on and select 'ability', it renders the `pokeData.map` but shows me the results for 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/berry' when it should be showing me the data for 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability' and this keeps happening on each select. It seems like the index is off by -1. I have a follow-up question as well, but I'd appreciate if someone can help me understand this. Thanks.

**So, i have a couple of problems here:**

1. Fix the issue with the index on the selectedItem, which is undef for the first selection and is set to index-1 on the next selections.
2. Perform the same thing using dropdown using material-ui. In which I do something like this:

```
const dropdownItems: [
  'item1',
  'item2',
  'item3',
];
```

and the dropdown looks like:

```
<dropdown> source={dropdownItems} onChange={this.handleDropdownChange} </dropdown>
```

How do i make this work? It doesn't work as shown above.

Comment: What do you use for your drop down ?

Comment: I want to do the exact same thing using the dropdown as well, which is material-ui wrapped internally by us. But, using the above, I am not able to get the onChange working. I mean nothing really happens when user selects a dropdown option if I try the code above.

Comment: Can you show us the drop-down internal code ? The onChange function should be called.

Comment: Sure, let me re-do the whole thing with the dropdown so I can show you that. Will get back to you. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: So, I tried to use the dropdown, which looks like this: <Dropdown source={dropdownItems} onChange={this.handleDropdownChange} /> and I'm using the same handleDropdownChange as I've pasted in my question above. But it throws up this error: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined, for the setState line: 
  84 | handleDropdownChange(e) {
> 85 |   this.setState({selectedValue: e.target.value})
Any ideas why it can't read the value?
----------------------------
Forgot to mention: const dropdownItems = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

Comment: I think you need to show the render function. Which drop-down component are you using? Because <Drop-down /> is not a material UI compoennt.

Comment: Ok, I'll post that on Sunday then. Going out for a couple of days. Thanks for your help so far. Appreciate every single minute you have put into this. Have a good weekend yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that setState is async. The value is not yet set when you call the fetch and the previous value will be used. For the first time that's undefined.

Either use the value directly in your call from the event or use the setState callback as second parameter to trigger the API call like this.

this.setState({selectedValue: e.target.value}, () => fetch(...)...)

It should also work the same for the drop down.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I should have thought of this earlier and it does seem obvious now that you have pointed it out :-)

Comment: It's quite a common problem that people have. So you are not the first ;)

Answer (score 0):

The setState method is async which means that you cannot guarantee it has finished before the fetch method is called and hence the value can sometimes be undefined.

```
fetch(taskAPI + this.state.selectedValue)
```

A simple solution would be to use e.target.value in the fetch request too or supply a callback function to the setState that fetches the information once the state has been set.

For more information on setState see - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

Hope the above clears up the issue!

~Fraz

Comment: Thank you.. Makes sense and appreciate your help sir!